# How to open camera lens mug without breaking it?

Tags: home, kitchen

I've received a gift in form of camera lens mug, but after pour in a hot beverage and closing the lid, I can't open it anymore.

Do you know any alternative methods to open it without breaking the glass?

I've tried with force, but without luck. I think the air is sucked and unlucky the screw is screwed in unequally.

[image: camera lens mug]

Comment: This will always happen if you allow the product to cool with the lid attached. The cooler air requires less volume than it did when warm and thus sucks the lid down. So once you figure out how to open this, bear in mind this will happen again if you're not careful. Side note: I'm totally getting one of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in a bowl of very hot water for 10 minutes to expand the low-pressure air and reduce the suction?  A dishwasher cycle might do it.

BTW I got one of these for Xmas and haven't yet used it,  so I could try and repeat the experiment!

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a strap wrench. They are usually used in plumbing where you don't want to mark something up with a normal wrench like on tub spouts, etc. That should give you a little extra torque without damaging the mug.

Answer (score 2):

Slide a butter knife between the rubber gasket and the metal base, it will open just enough to release the pressure. The lid will easily come off after the hissing stops. Any thin object that can lift the gasket slightly will work.

This is not speculation, It worked for me just now and did not damage my mug or cap in any way.